# How to fix this duplicate function definition error?

Tags: actionscript-3, encoding, flash-cs6

I am totally new at Flash CS6 Action script 3. I have to do an assignment of a scene that have to have mouse, keyboard, enter frame, and time events. Every time I test the movie out, I keep on getting an error that says, 'duplicate function definition' about the 'enter frame event' and 'timer event' functions'. I have tried to rename the functions, but it didn't work. Is there another solution to this? Also, could you please show some examples? Thanks!

```
QuestionMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
QuestionMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, questionOver);
QuestionMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, questionOut);

function questionOver(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.alpha = .5;
}

function questionOut(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.alpha = 1;
}

function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //trace("click!!!");
    event.target.y -= 15;
    event.target.rotation += 45;
}

QuestionMC.buttonMode = true;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, jump);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, land);

function jump (event:KeyboardEvent): void
{
    trace(event.keyCode);
    YoshiMC.y -= 50
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, jump);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, flip);
}
function land (event:KeyboardEvent): void
{
    YoshiMC.y += 50
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, jump);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, flip);
}
function flip(event:Event):void
{
    YoshiMC.rotation += 45;
    YoshiMC.x += 20;
}
var jumpTimer:Timer = new Timer(5000,1);
jumpTimer.addEventListener(TimeEvent.TIMER, jump);
function jump (event:TimerEvent):void
{
    planteaterMC.play();
}
jumpTimer.start();

var link:URLRequest = new URLRequest("");

buttongoeshere.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHere);

function clickHere(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(link);
}
buttongoeshere.buttonMode = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `jump` function is declared twice, here:

```
function jump (event:KeyboardEvent): void
```

and here:

```
function jump (event:TimerEvent):void
```

You just need to rename one of them